# Save image into library directly from APNS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

i want to save image into photo library of iphone sdk. my image is coming from one url and that url is coming from APNS. basically i want save image directly into iphone lib without opening app when user will click on that URL which is coming as Push notification. right now i am doing this as follows but i dont want to show that image i just want to save.

```
-(void) sshowansimage:(NSString *) strImageURL
{

     NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:strImageURL];
     NSLog(@"coming URL is %@", strImageURL);
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
          NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:strImageURL];
          [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showImage:) withObject:imageData waitUntilDone:YES];
     });

}

-(void)showImage:(NSData*)imageAsData
{
     NSLog(@"IN image view mthhod data is %d",imageAsData.length);
     ansinage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageAsData];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for store image directly to Photo Album

```
 UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData: imageData];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: how to open library means? Do you want to open UIImagePicker Controller

Comment: ok then just add the image picker method in appDelegate and call it in your view controller by creating appdelegete object

Answer (score 1):

you can use your image as NSData and store it to albums with following.first you need to convert your NSData in to image object and then do following.

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```